# Call to a member function beginTransaction() on null while parallel testing Laravel using PostgreSQL

Tags: laravel, postgresql, testing

Initially my testsuite was using in memory sqlite database but I'm adapting it to using postgresql, the same as the production database, because some features rely on specific postgresql features and tests weren't being correctly written because of this.

The problem is I'm having problems running tests in parallel. If I run the tests "normally" (`php artisan test`) the testsuite runs fine.

However, if I run tests in parallel (`php artisan test --parallel`) some tests cause an error:

```
Error: Call to a member function beginTransaction() on null

vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/ManagesTransactions.php:177
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/ManagesTransactions.php:143
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/ManagesTransactions.php:117
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/ManagesTransactions.php:24
...
```

AFAIK, the `getPdo()` method in the `PostgresConnection` class return `null` sometimes but can't figure out why.

I'm using the `LazilyRefreshDatabase` trait to manage database refreshes.

As I said earlier, if I run the testsuite sequentially it runs fine. Only if I run in parallel I get the error.

Any ideas on what the problem could be or how I can try and debug it?

Thanks in advance.